# What does it mean "to get one to gut level"?

Tags: idioms

The sentence where the expression is used is the following: I started my talk with a seductive dance because I wanted you first to feel the seduction, **to get you kind of to gut level.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me say, the sentence is confusing, and I wouldn't say "get you to a gut level". I have never heard someone say this. Since this is not a common expression, I can only guess at the meaning. However, I'm pretty sure the meaning is this:

"Gut" in this case means intuition. Common phrases using the word "gut" are "trust your gut" (decide using your instinct/emotions), "feel it in my gut" (something deeply resonates with you) and "gut reaction" (a response based off of emotions rather than logic)

So in this context, it most likely means that the narrator in your sentence wants to seduce someone so that he/she will make decisions based on emotions and arousal, rather than on logic.

Comment: "get you at gut level" might be more common than "get you to gut level"

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I think there we're dealing with different senses of *get*. You're reading *get* in the "have an effect upon, impact" sense (*Her remarks got me where it hurt*), but I think the sense the original intends is "cause to arrive at, bring to" (*Working with her got me to a new level of productivity*).

Comment: Thank you all. You have elucidated the meaning of the sentence. Now, the meaning of the "gut" and its possible usage is clear for me. Just, if you are interested, the sentence is from TEDx talk. Here is the link to that talk. https://youtu.be/TBIL2sdfoVc?t=1m12s